# Join two tables and populate a first table column with data from the second (not "update function" available)

Tags: mysql

I would like to join two table keep all the records from the first and populate a given column of the first one with a record from the second

See the ss attached of the structure of the table (don't know how to keep the formatting i choose for the table here)
thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gV7q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just update the first table with the second table's data?

```
UPDATE `FirstTable` AS T1, `SecondTable` AS T2 
SET T1.cost = T2.cost
WHERE T1.Primary_key = T2.Primary_key;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. My question wasn't really clear. i'm using a cloud datawahouse system that supports only join (outer, inner, left and right). so i can't use update. do you have any idea how i can do that?